# How to update a MongoDB collections with an unknown number of possible fields using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update a mongodb collection without knowing exactly how many and which fields will be used to update. For example, if I have a user and they update information about them on different pages then it will not always be the same fields that are updated.

Below is my current idea for how to approach this but I am open to alternatives.

```
app.post("/user", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  // req.body can consist of 1 or more of the following { FirstName, LastName, Email, Interests, UserRole }
  const CreatedAt = Date.now();

  if (req.body.Name) {
    let promise = User.findOne({ Name: req.body.Name });
      promise.then(user => {
        for (let key in req.body) {
          // Name will print but nothing else, nothing is updated either and there are no errors
          console.log(key);
          User
            .where({_id: user._id })
            .setOptions({ multi: true })
            .update({ $set: { [key]: key } })
            .update({ $set: { UpdatedAt: Date.now() } })
            .catch(err => res.json({message:"Failed to update the database."}));
        }
      }).catch(err => res.json({message:"User could not be found."}));

  } else {
     res.json({message:"Please provide an email and a password."});
  };
});
```

The big issue here is that I do not know which field or fields will be updated and I do not want to make an long if that check if each of the following possible values are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html) you can just change the fields and save it:

```
app.post("/user", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  //req.body can consist of 1 or more of the following 
  //  { FirstName, LastName, Email, Interests, UserRole }
  const CreatedAt = Date.now();

  if (req.body.Name) {
    User.findOne({ Name: req.body.Name })
    .then(user => {
      //mutate user:
      Object.keys(req.body).reduce(
        (user,key)=>{
          user[key]=req.body[key];
          return user;
        }
        ,user
      );
      //set UpdatedAt
      user.UpdatedAt = Date.now();
      //http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html
      //  maybe outdated, does not mention promise but
      //  you could try return user.save()
      return new Promise(
        (resolve,reject)=>
          user.save(
            (err,user)=>
              (err)
                ? reject(err)
                : resolve(user)
          )
      )
    })
    .then(user=>res.json({message:user}))
    .catch(err => res.json({message:"User could not be found."}));
  } else {
    res.json({message:"Please provide an email and a password."});
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer is perfect! But just for added clarification, why are you using reduce instead of foreach? Doesn't the value only need to be access and not being summed up? I am only asking because I have never really used a reduce function for much more than combining numbers or strings?

Comment: @Brandon you can use reduce to turn any list of values and return one. in this case `Object.keys(req.body).forEach` would work just as as well.